# Color coding points on graph depending on the X-axis

Tags: python, plotly

I have a graph in plotly. Essentially what i am trying to do is change the color of each point on the graph if the y-axis value is any of the values in a given list.

For example:

```
list = ["ACACT", "TATTC", "CGATT"]
```

If this was my graph i want to make all the points corresponding to any of the values in list red.

[image: Plotly Graph]

My current graph code is:

```
trace = go.scatter(
      x = x1,
      y = x2,
      mode = 'markers'
)
data = [trace]
py.iplot(data, filename='basic-scatter')
```

I know you can edit the marker using

```
marker = dict()
```

But can you do it for specific points like I am trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a list of colors to [`color`](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#scatter-marker-color) in `marker`, e.g.

```
go.Scatter(x=x
           y=y,
           mode='markers',
           marker={'color': colors})
```

In the example below a default color is used for all points, but a few ones are colored differently based on a `dict` which uses the y-axis value as its key and the color as the value.

[image]

```
import random 
import plotly 
plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode()

# generate some random x and y-values 
n_points = 10 
y = [] 
for i in range(4):
    _y = 'AT' + 'ATGC'[i]
    y.extend([_y + nuc for nuc in 'ATGC']) 
x = [random.random() for _ in range(n_points * len(y))] 
y = y * n_points

# the default color 
default_color = 'rgb(0,0,255)'

# define our special colors 
special_colors = {'ATAT': 'rgb(255, 0, 0)',
                  'ATTA': 'rgb(0, 255, 0)'}

# build a list of custom 
colors colors = []
for i, y_value in enumerate(y):
    colors.append(special_colors.get(y_value, default_color))

fig = plotly.graph_objs.Figure() 
fig.add_scatter(x=x, y=y, mode='markers', marker={'color': colors}) 
plotly.offline.iplot(fig)
```